# What would a moderately more advanced society on Earth do to stop a pandemic?

Tags: science-based, technology, diseases

The Coronavirus is spreading all over the world and it seems to be airborne, highly contagious and hard to contain. If I survive, I want to write a pandemic story. Let’s say there is an airborne virus spreading around Earth that is almost a Type 1 civilization. There is no cure and no vaccine. The society has some interplanetary presence on orbital bodies (like the Moon and Mars) but only the very rich can afford to live there and it’s too expensive and difficult to evacuate the Earth. Aside from quarantining (which doesn’t always work), how would their scientific efforts try to stop the disease from becoming a pandemic?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems more about idea generation than solving a particular wb problem. Entire books can be written exploring this idea and different routes that the Type I civilisation could take or not take. I recommend continuing with this idea and making it the backbone of your narrative. Make your exploration of the different options be story devices to drive your plot. When you have specific problems...we'd be glad to help!

Comment: Watch https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contagion_(2011_film) Nothing on the "more advanced" line but it will show you you have good chances to survive and there are lots of things to go through until the "doom panic" is warranted - I don't know, maybe your book will be better for it.

Comment: The coronavirus is airborne only in the sense that you can catch it from being sneezed on. It is not 'highly contagious', its a respiratory syndrome, and as such, very basic measures like proper sanitation and moderate levels of containment are enough to heavily clamp down on it's spread. Not to mention that, given access to decent medical care, the fatality rate is very low.

Comment: You'll survive, Max.  You don't have much to worry about unless you are an infant or elderly.  More people die in the US from the flu every year than are predicted to die from the coronavirus outbreak.

Comment: Voting to close as "needs details or clarity". I don't think this is off-topic because it fits within the framework of building a fictional world, and your given circumstances are valid. But without getting specifics on the virus or a particular containment scenario / focus, there are far too many possible answers.

Comment: the idea that "the rich" would even _want_ to live on "orbital bodies" (which i wouldn't count the Mars in), see also "Elysium", is quite absurd. "The rich" will always be able to make a cosy nest for themselves here on Earth much better than anywhere else. They'll rather send the poor sods to work the asteroid mines.

Answer (score 1):

**Virtualization and robotics**

Pandemic is fueled by people's contact. Stop the contact, stop the pandemic.

Our current civilization very much depends on people gathering together, or at least meeting each other in order to do their job. Factory workers are assembling together in a factory, office workers flock to the office, retail workers go to their stores, and so on. But we can see how technology is changing that. Robots taking over humans in factories, office workers are able to work from virtually everywhere, and retail industry is yielding to e-commerce.

In the future we may assume that there trends will continue, and people, if they want to, may never leave their homes while keeping various jobs.

If global pandemic strikes, government would simply cancel all public gatherings and events. Private companies would close their offices. But life will go on. Economy would not crater. Isolated people would stop spreading the virus, and pandemic would eventually end.

Hospitals would be impossible to close down. But over there robotics would help too. Instead of donning mask and gloves and praying that it should provide sufficient protection, a doctor would send their robotic assistant to patient's room. This robot wouldn't catch the disease, and can be thoroughly sterilized between the visits.